# getting heap corruption and program crashing

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have written following to solve following problem
"Given a list of unsorted numbers, can you find the numbers that have the smallest absolute difference between them? If there are multiple pairs, find them all."

Here is code

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <deque>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int* smallestDiff(vector<int> a,int &noOfPairs)
{
    sort(a.begin(),a.end());
    int * arr = new int(a.size()* sizeof(int) *2);
    bool bfoundDiff = false;
    int smallestDiff =0;
    int num1,num2;
    for(size_t i=0;i<a.size()-1;i++)
    {
        num1 = a[i];
        num2 = a[i+1];

        int newDiff = num2-num1;
        if(!bfoundDiff || newDiff < smallestDiff)
        {
            smallestDiff = newDiff;
            arr[0] = num1;
            arr[1]= num2;
            noOfPairs = 1;
            bfoundDiff = true;
        }
    }

    for(size_t i=0;i<a.size()-1;i++)
    {
        num1 = a[i];
        num2 = a[i+1];
        int newDiff = num2-num1;
        if(newDiff == smallestDiff && num1!=arr[0] && num2!=arr[1])
        {
            arr[noOfPairs*2] = num1;
            arr[noOfPairs*2 + 1] = num2;
            ++noOfPairs;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
int main() {

    int _a_size;
    cin >> _a_size;
    cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
    vector<int> _a;
    int _a_item;
    for(int _a_i=0; _a_i<_a_size; _a_i++) {
        cin >> _a_item;
        _a.push_back(_a_item);
    }
    int noOfPairs=0;
    int *result =smallestDiff(_a,noOfPairs);
    int noOfelems = noOfPairs*2;
    for(int i=0;i<noOfelems;++i)
    {
        cout<< *(result+i)<<" ";
    }
     return 0;
}
```

Now program is running fine as per logic but its crashing when it tries to print result values.I dont see anything wrong with passing pointer as return type.

Do you guys see any issue here?

Comment: what are the inputs you are passing?

Comment: 5 as number of items and numbers as 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: How do you know the program logic is fine, if the output crashes? I suspect it has something to do with declaring int* arrays and using pointers within that. Switching to a vector seems the easiest and best solution.

Comment: Do you maybe also want `int * arr = new int[a.size()* 2];`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just return a vector instead?  You're using vector elsewhere already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a typo in the following line:

```
int * arr = new int(a.size()* sizeof(int) *2);
```

It should be like this:

```
int * arr = new int[a.size()* sizeof(int) *2];
```

Instead of allocating an array you allocate single integer and initialize it with what you think had to be size.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` is handled by `new[]`.

Comment: How can I miss that :(